# What story or franchise had a war with the Sleem?

Tags: story-identification

Today I was talking about [Spore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spore_(2008_video_game)) (the video game) and how there are aliens called the Grox who are powerful and taking over the galaxy. During that I was reminded of another dangerous galactic empire that was mysterious in some story called the Sleem.

If I recall correctly they were not contacted during the story but there were rumors of the Sleem and how they are powerful and evil. And I remember something about a photo of a star with a wedge shaped ship in silhouette in front of it. The person describing the photo is saying the ship design seems straightforward but it’s much, much bigger than it appears to be. If I remember there’s something about “we have to make peace/conquer our immediate enemy quickly because the Sleem are coming”.

I'm not certain whether it was a novel or short story or part of a universe. I'm pretty sure it’s not a movie or TV series or video game.

It *might* be from the [Continuing Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Keys_Moran#The_Continuing_Time) universe of Daniel Keyes Moran. It might be something from Niven’s [Known Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known_Space), such as Man-Kzin wars, but I don’t think it’s that.

I might have the name “Sleem” wrong, but until my web searches turned up nothing on that I was 100% confident that was their name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Writing the question got me to the answer. It **is** from The Continuing Time, the Daniel Keyes Moran universe. Specifically, the sleem are talked about in the third novel, *The Last Dancer*:

> In over thirty-two hundred years, no ship of the Flame People had ever triumphed in combat against the sleem; some few had survived to escape.

<sup>— [The Last Dancer](https://a.co/iORkfLw) (Tales of the Continuing Time Book 3) by Daniel Keys Moran</sup>

This explains why it is hard to find with a web search - Moran has just never been that popular.

Comment: Searching for "The sleem" (in quote marks) would have got you there. Moran's books are the first ten answer on my search

Comment: @Valorum Not true for me. You've trained Google to know you well, I think. Closest thing I found was a Doctor Who reference. Beyond that it's Ancestry.com, Urban Dictionary, a coat of arms web site, and then some microscopy of semiconducting materials web sites.

Comment: I'm sure at this point, @Valorum simply needs to open Google, start typing `"`, and it knows what they're looking for.  I tried searching `"the sleem"` as well, and didn't get anything mentioning Moran either on the first two pages of results.